# c++ order of cout with variables in struct changes the content?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm having an odd problem. I have a practice exercise with pointers and the results are coming out differently depending on the order of cout statements. Depending on of the two struct variables I cout first, they come out differently. More specifically, the struct Student has two variables, name and gpa. After setting up the variables, if I cout gpa then name, gpa is fine and name is not; if I cout name then gpa, name is fine and gpa is not. Any idea why?

This is the code, with name then gpa output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    char * name;
    float gpa;
};

Student *createStudent(char name[], float gpa);

int main()
{
    int     MAX = 100;
    float   stuGpa = 0;
    char    *stuName = new char[MAX];

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    stuName = "fubar";
    stuGpa = 4.0;

    Student *student1;
    student1 = new Student;
    student1 = createStudent(stuName, stuGpa);

    // cout name (first)
    cout << "\nStudent name is " << student1->name;

    // cout gpa (second)
    cout << "\nStudent gpa is " << student1->gpa;

    return 0;
}

Student *createStudent(char name[], float gpa)
{
    int length = strlen(name);
    Student newStudent;
    newStudent.gpa = gpa;
    newStudent.name = new char[length];
    newStudent.name = name;
    return &newStudent; //return the address of the newly created student
}
```

My output:

```
Student name is fubar
Student gpa is 0.00
```

If I reverse the cout statements, the output is

```
Student gpa is 4.00
Student name is
```

Any idea why the cout order is affecting the content of the struct variables?

Comment: you should really read the [compiler warnings](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mFk7JIrfAqvNwBYc)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are returning the address of a local variable:

```
Student *createStudent(char name[], float gpa)
{
    Student newStudent; // <-------- here
    return &newStudent; //return the address of the newly created student
}
```

The newly-created student only lives so long as the `createStudent` function is executing . It gets destroyed when `}` is reached. You returned a pointer to an object that no longer exist.

You also have a memory leak in the main function:

```
student1 = new Student;   // point "student1" to a newly allocated Student
student1 = createStudent(stuName, stuGpa);  // point it elsewhere
```

The object created by "new" no longer has any pointers to it, because you made "student1" point elsewhere.

There is another such leak in:

```
stuName = new char[MAX];    // point stuName at some allocated memory
stuName = "fubar";          // point stuName at "fubar" instead
```

This is the sort of mess you get into when using pointers and `new`.

To fix this mess your best option is to make the following changes:

- Return `Student`, not `Student *`
- Use `Student` , not `Student *` in the main function
- Change `char * name` to `std::string name`
- Change `char    *stuName = new char[MAX];` to `std::string stuName;`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my noob mistake with the local instance of student1 in createStudent. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the pointers because they're part of the assignment (and I really prefer working with strings, so I'd love to take your advice), so I moved the Student initialization into main and added a parameter to createStudent to pass the Student pointer to it.